# Perl: Dynamic module loading, object inheritance and "common helper files"

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, perl-module, autoload

In a nutshell I try to model a network topology using objects for every instance in the network. Additionally I got a top-level manager class responsible for, well, managing these objects and performing integrity checks. The filestructure looks like this (I left out most of the object-files as they are all structured pretty equal):

```
Manager.pm
Constants.pm
Classes/
  +- Machine.pm
  +- Node.pm
  +- Object.pm
  +- Switch.pm
```

Coming from quite a few years in OOP, I'm a fan of code reuse etc. so I set up inheritance between thos objects, the inheritance tree (in this example) looks like this:

```
Switch  -+-> Node -+-> Object
Machine -+
```

All those objects are structured like this:

```perl
package Switch;
use parent qw(Node);

sub buildFromXML {
  ...
}
sub new {
  ...
}

# additonal methods
```

Now the interesting part:

## Question 1

How can I ensure correct loading of all those objects without typing out the names statically?
The underlying problem is: If I just `require "$_" foreach glob("./Classes/*");` I get many "Subroutine new redefined at" errors. I also played around with `use parent qw(-norequire Object)`, `Module::Find` and some other `@INC` modifications in various combinations, to make it short: It didn't work. Currently I'm statically importing all used classes, they auto-import their parent classes.
So basically what I'm asking: What is the (perl-)correct way of doing this?
And advanced: It would be very helpful to be able to create a more complex folder structure (as there will be quite a few objects) and still have inheritance + "autoloading"

## Question 2 - **SOLVED**

How can I "share my imports"? I use several libraries (my own, containing some helper functions, `LibXML`, `Scalar::Util`, etc.) and I want to share them amongst my objects. (The reasoning behind that is, I may need to add another common library to all objects and chances are high that there will be well above 100 objects - no fun editing all of them manually and doing that with a regex / script would theoretically work but that doesn't seem like the cleanest solution available)
What I tried:

- import everything in `Manager.pm` -> Works inside the Manager package - gives me errors like "undefined subroutine &Switch::trace called"
- Create a `include.pl` file and `do`/`require`/`use` it inside every object - gives me the same errors.
- Some more stuff I sadly don't remember

`include.pl` basically would look like that:

```
use lib_perl;
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed);
use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper;
use Error::TryCatch;
...
```

Again I ask: What's the correct way to do it? Am I using the right approach and just failing at the execution or should I change my structure completely?
It doesn't matter that much why my current code doesn't work that well, providing a correct, clean approach for those problems would be enough by far :)

EDIT: Totally forgot perl version -_- Sidenote: I can't upgrade perl, as I need libraries that are stuck with 5.8 :/

```
C:\> perl -version
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 50 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall

Binary build 820 [274739] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Jan 23 2007 15:57:46
```

Comment: I was just passing (don't have time to wade through that lot, sorry) and I noticed you have `package Switch;` and you are on 5.8.  There was a core module called `Switch` in 5.8 (Damian's ill-fated "case" statement), so that's a bad idea.

Comment: Internally I use SwitchDescription as package name, I chose the short name only for the sake of readability, so that shouldn't be a problem. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a partial answer to question 2, sharing imports.

Loading a module (via `use`) does two things:

1. Compiling the module and installing the contents in the namespace hierarchy (which is shared). See `perldoc -f require`.
2. Calling the `import` sub on each loaded module. This loads some subs or constants etc. into the namespace of the caller. This is a process that the `Exporter` class largely hides from view. This part is important to use subs etc. without their full name, e.g. `max` instead of `List::Util::max`. See `perldoc -f use`.

Lets view following three modules: `A`, `B` and `User`.

```
{
   package A;
   use List::Util qw(max);
   # can use List::Util::max
   # can use max
}
{
   package User;
   # can use List::Util::max -> it is already loaded
   # cannot use max, this name is not defined in this namespace
}
```

Package `B` defines a sub `load` that loads a predefined list of modules and subs into the callers namespace:

```
{
   package B;
   sub load {
     my $package = (caller())[0]; # caller is a built-in, fetches package name

     eval qq{package $package;} . <<'FINIS' ;
       use List::Util qw(max);
       # add further modules here to load
       # you can place arbitrarily complex code in this eval string
       # to execute it in all modules that call this sub.
       # (e.g. testing and registering)
       # However, this is orthogonal to OOP.
FINIS

     if ($@) {
       # Do error handling
     }
   }
}
```

Inside the `eval`'d string, we temporarily switch into the callers package and then load the specified module. This means that the `User` package code now looks like this:

```
{
   package User;
   B::load();
   # can use List::Util::max
   # can use max
}
```

However, you have to make sure the `load` sub is already loaded itself. `use B` if in doubt. It might be best to execute `B::load()` in the `BEGIN` phase, before the rest of the module is compiled:

```
{
  package User;
  BEGIN {use B; B::load()}
  # ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
  package User;
  use B;
  use List::Util qw(max);
  # ...
}
```

TIMTOWTDI. Although I find `eval`ing code quite messy and dangerous, it is the way I'd pursue in this scenario (rather than `do`ing files, which is similar but has different side effects). Manually messing with typeglobs in the package namespace is hell in comparision, and copy-pasting a list of module names is like going back to the days when there wasn't even C's preprocessor.

---

#### Edit: [`Import::Into`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emstrout/Import-Into-1.001000/lib/Import/Into.pm)

… is a CPAN module providing this functionality via an interesting method interface. Using this module, we would redefine our `B` package the following way:

```
{
  package B;
  use List::Util;   # you have to 'use' or 'require' this first, before using 'load'.
  use Import::Into; # has to be installed from CPAN first
  sub load {
    my $package = caller;
    List::Util->import::into($package, qw(max));
    # should work too: strict->import::into($package);
    # ...
  }
}
```

This module hides all the dirty work (`eval`ing) from view and does method call resolution gymnastics to allow importing pragmas into other namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also thought of something like that, but as you said, `eval`ing **is** kinda messy and I'd rather only use it as a "last resort" solution. BTW what may be worth noting in your first snippet: if `package User` has a `use A` directive in it, you should be able to call `A::max` inside the `User` package. This train of thought helped me understanding the principles of `use` and `require` a lot

Comment: @Megge The problem is that the `package` function doesn't take an arbitrary expression, so the namespace has to be hardcoded. So without `evaling` it is difficult (impossible?) to switch into a namespace specified at runtime. `import`ing happens only into the current package :( And yes, `A::max` is available, but using that doesn't feel right.

Comment: The thing is I have the impression that there should be a halfway decent approach in a "new" language like perl. Maybe there is a solution / a module that uses a completely different approach. I'll just wait if anyone comes up with a solution over the weekend, if not I'll use yours.

Comment: @Megge Actually, there is a module that does this: [`Import::Into`](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/Import-Into-1.001000/lib/Import/Into.pm). Suprise, it uses `eval` too, and just provides syntactic sugar using some *really* funky code … (Perl—a "new" language? born 1987 — only 4 years younger than C++ —reborn 1994 as Perl 5, it has a longer history than either Python or Java)

Comment: Good thing about that sugar is, it (should) work and I have one problem less to care about :) Does "really funky" mean "should not use" or would you recommend it? ("New" in a sense that it's not something like BASIC, Fortran etc. and it has OOP. Perl feels so intuitive regarding so many aspects that it really seems strange that such a common task does not have a solid solution. (On the other hand I had my first encounter with perl only 4 weeks ago, so the "intuitive" feeling might fade soon ;) )

Comment: "Funky" means: I didn't understand the code on first sight. But now that I do, it is absolutely beautiful and it does have a few edges over my approach. I am adding a short usage section to my post in a minute.

Comment: Thanks alot! I guess Question #2 is answered. I guess if I mark your answer as solution, the whole question gets marked as solved, so I'll accept your answer when everything is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to Import::Into Solution

I found a scenario that seems to require eval() from within the Import::Into solution.  In this scenario, mod User is effectively among the uses from package B.  This may be a common scenario for people using Import::Into.

Specifics:

- I created module uses_exporter with separate subs for importing
  different groups of modules, e.g. load_generic() and
  load_list_utils().
- The uses in load_list_utils() are to public mods like
  List::MoreUtils, AND to a module of my own, list_utils_again. That
  local module also calls load_list_utils().  The call fails if
  load_list_utils() uses list_utils_again.
- My solution was to put the use to list_utils_again into an eval which
  does not excecute when $target eq 'list_utils_again'

Answer (score 0):

The correct idiomatic Perl way to do this is *not* to always load a bunch a modules whether used or not; it is to have every file `use` those modules it directly (not indirectly) needs.

If it turns out that *every* file uses the same set of modules, you might make things simpler by having a single dedicated module to use all those in that common set.